# Changing time format in python using datetime

Tags: python, parsing, datetime

I am having trouble trying to change my date format.

`mydate` is for example: 2017-06-20T12:54:57.000Z

Here what I am trying to do: `datetime.strptime('mytime', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m:%sZ')`

I also tried `dateutil.parser.parse('mydate').strptime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%m:%sZ')`

For both I have this error:
[image: link to screenshot]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors, copy the text as text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

`%m` stands for months; the second time you should've used `%M` for minutes. Also, `%S` for seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format string:

```
datetime.strptime(mytime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

In yours, you have `%m` instead of `%M` for the minute, `%s` instead of `%S` for the second, and you were missing the `%f` for the microsecond.

Check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for a full explanation of datetime string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I finally split my string because I don't need the microseconds, and I use timedelta to correct the timezone